# parsing the number in the end

Tags: c#

Given:

```
Test123
Test 23
Test  456
```

What are some ways to get the number (that's on the end) and place in an number variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var re = new Regex(@"(\d+)$");
(new List<String>(new[]{
    "Test123",
    "Test 123",
    "Test:123"
})).ForEach(t =>
{
    var m = re.Match(t);
    Int32 n = Int32.Parse(m.Captures[0].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => Found: {1}", t, n);
});
```

output:

```
Test123 => Found: 123
Test 123 => Found: 123
Test:123 => Found: 123
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/JGgEd

Comment: you don't need brackets if you use `Captures[0].Value`, just use `@"\d+$"`. Brackets are for grouping.

Comment: @Andrey: Indeed, just copy-pasted from a regex tester I was using. No matter how simple the expression, I still like to test it. ;-)

Comment: totally agree, that's why I tested my suggestion before posting :) it works without brackets :)

Answer (score 7):

Use a RegEx like `\d+$` - this will match all the numbers at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way:

```
char[] nonZeroDigits = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','9' };
int numberStart = value.IndexOfAny(nonZeroDigits);
int result = 0;
if (numberStart != -1)
    int.TryParse(value.Substring(numberStart), out result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like Oded said you could do this

```
int i = Regex.IsMatch(input,@"\d+$") ? Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(input,@"\d+$").Value) : 0;
```

Comment: Great one! It is better to save `Match` as variable and check for success, instead of doing same thing twice

Comment: I agree, just threw something up quick :)

Answer (score 0):

Oded's answer is good. Here is a non regex answer that uses LINQ:

```
string s = "Test 123";
string remainingNums = new string(s.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsNumber(c)).ToArray());
int asInt = 0;
bool succeeded = int.TryParse(remainingNums, out asInt);
```

Comment: Did you try that on `"Test 123 more text"`? Not sure that is a possible input for the OP, but it doesn't hhurt to be safe.

Comment: The OP said the numbers are on the end. All other answers on this page rely on that fact as well.

Comment: It is slow and bloated solution compared to Regex.

Comment: @Matt: yes, the question says *"What are some ways to get the number (that's on the end)*", but it does not say that all input will conform to this pattern. My experience is that the assumption that all input follows the pattern almost always comes back to bite you. But given that the input follows the pattern, your solution will work.

Comment: @Andrey -- regex solution when repeated 999,999 times took 13,321 milliseconds. My solution when repeated 999,999 times took 699 milliseconds. Not only is my solution faster, it's orders of magnitude faster. http://pastebin.com/fZisyHfq

Comment: @Matt Greer  1) use compiled regex 2) don't use groups, use `Captures`. After that Regex will work for ~700ms vs ~500ms of your method on my PC. Plus Regex doesn't add pressure to GC and creating a lot of strings does.

Comment: @Matt Greer after adding `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` Regex works even faster.

Comment: @Andrey yet even with compiled regex my solution is still faster. Never assume :)

Comment: @Matt Greer ok, but I still consider it bloated :)

Comment: @Andrey - with a compiled regex it took over 20 *minutes* to do it 999,999 times. Compiling a regex is very expensive. Moving the compilation outside of the for loop really is a different comparison.

Comment: @Matt Greer are you serious? Compile Regex *once*. No, it is same comparison. Pattern doesn't change, then why to recompile regex everytime?

Comment: Because we are comparing one instance of the operation against the other. The only reason we have to do it so many times is to get a meaningful reading. That's how benchmarks work. If you compile it once, that is a different operation. What if the user only needs to do this once? Then my approach is faster (in fact, much faster). If they need to do it 10,000 times, then a regex is probably faster. Different approaches for different situations. When comparing apples to apples, you need to make sure everything is an apple :)

Comment: And of course in almost every situation this operation won't be an app's bottleneck so all of these speed comparisons are ultimately meaningless. Premature optimization and all that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Char.IsNumber` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y.aspx) to find a number substring and then you can use `int.Parse`